# simplifying regular expression

Tags: regex, simplification

I am going through exercises regarding regular expressions, and I am really unsure on how to do this.

The regular expression is:

```
((a*)(b*))* ∪ (a*)
```

I am really bad at this, but I think that `((a*)(b*))*` can be simplified to `(a ∪ b)*` But if this is right, than the last `∪ (a*)` is really just a repetition, so I figure the whole expression can be simplified to `(a ∪ b)*.` Does this seem correct?

Edit: ∪ stands for union

Comment: Does `U` stand for union? That is, with `(a U b)*` do you actually mean what would be expressed in regex as `(a|b)*` or `[ab]*`? Cause if so that pattern you have seems equal to just `(a|b)*` like you suggested.

Comment: If `U` is supposed to mean "union", then it would be appropriate to use the proper symbol (`∪`) - or at least state it in the text.

Comment: @Tomalak, how do you use the union symbol?

Comment: @perreal It's [a normal Unicode character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/222a/index.htm), you can insert it verbatim. Of course, if all client fonts contain a representation of that character, that's a different matter.

Comment: Wouldn't that question better belong to [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-languages) as it's kind of confusing here :]

Comment: @Jonny5 I agree, this question should be closed or moved due to nature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. `(a*b*)*` can match any string of a's and b's, so can `(a U b)*`, therefore they are equivalent. `(a U b)*` intersect `a*` is `a*` so `a*` is a subset of `(a U b)*`. Consequently, the whole expression can be simplified to `(a U b)*`.

Comment: You are wrong. `(a U b)*` will match literal `a U b` zero or more times. It is no longer what original regex was intended to match.

Comment: why do you say that? Union and OR are exactly the same thing. and this question is about formal regular languages.

Comment: They are not in context of regex. `(a | b)*` is wrong expression too. OP did not state that he is asking about _format regular languages_ or anything like that. He added `regex` tag and asked about regex. So question should be downvoted and you should use proper regex symbols, to answer regex questions. Every character used in expression counts.

Comment: Because it is: literal `a ` OR literal ` b`, zero or more times. Original regex was much more about `a`'s and `b`'s, not about abstract units.

Answer (score -2):

What `((a*)(b*))*U(a*)` really means is (copied from [here](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28%28a%2a%29%28b%2a%29%29%2aU%28a%2a%29))

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1 (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      a*                       'a' (0 or more times (matching the
                               most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      b*                       'b' (0 or more times (matching the
                               most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  U                        'U'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \4:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    a*                       'a' (0 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \4
```

This expression currently matches all of these sequences: `abUa bU U aabbUaa aaUaa aaU Uaa bbU ababUaa aabbaabbUaa` (look at [here](http://www.rubular.com/r/rW3Ba8l9cs))

There is no way to simplify this, without removing capturing groups and remaining order of letters.

EDIT: If `U` in your regex statement stands for "union", then this expression is invalid. There is no way to union anything in regex. There is only `OR` and you need to use `|` (pipe) for that. If you want to union `((a*)(b*))*` and `(a*)` then probably it will be `((a*)(b*))*`, but it will still match anything like `abaab`.

Still, capturing groups in your regex statement are useless, so something like `[ab]*` is enough to match any number of `a`'s and `b`'s.

Comment: There are no captures, they are non-capturing groups in the OP.

Comment: Since `U` stands for union in this case (see comments to OP's question) your explanation is unfortunately not correct (it assumes `U` is the character `"U"`). It was very ambiguous and not your fault though.

Comment: @perreal Non capturing groups are `(?:)` OP uses `()`

Comment: @Deele, The question is not about Perl but regular expressions and languages in general.

Comment: @perreal Where OP is stating this?